# How to initialize non-final parameters in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, oop, variables, constructor

I want to receive a string for image. But I want to edit it afterwards in state for Dropdownmenu using widget.image. I am getting warning -
`This class (or a class that this class inherits from) is marked as '@immutable', but one or more of its instance fields aren't final: Dropdownmenu.dropdown value dart must_be_immutable`

````
  final List<String> options;
  final Function onchange;
  String dropdownvalue;
  Dropdownmenu(this.options, this.dropdownvalue, this.onchange);

  @override
  _DropdownmenuState createState() => _DropdownmenuState();
}```


What should I do?
````

Comment: `Widget`s are expected to be immutable.  If you need a mutable value, that value should be stored in a `StatefulWidget`'s corresponding  `State` object.  That's what it's for.  The corresponding `State` object can get its *initial* value from its `Widget`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned before, you can't modify a final field. For this reason, I recommend that you create another variable inside your widget and use the final value (which you pass to the widget) as the initial value. Then, modify the new variable instead.

Code example:

```
class DropDownWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final String initialImageString;
  const DropDownWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.initialImageString,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<DropDownWidget> createState() => _DropDownWidgetState();
}

class _DropDownWidgetState extends State<DropDownWidget> {
  String imageString = "";

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
      imageString = widget.initialImageString;
    });
  }

  void modifyImageString({required String newValue}) {
    setState(() {
      imageString = newValue;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  final List<String>? options;
  final Function? onchange;
  final String dropdownvalue;
  const Dropdownmenu({
    this.options,
    this.dropdownvalue = "default value",
    this.onchange,
  });

  @override
  _DropdownmenuState createState() => _DropdownmenuState();
}
```

Comment: No, I can't modify value of dropdownvalue if I initialize it with final.